# Кто знает как пофиксить?

Tags: c++

Обновил проект с VS2013 на vs2017 и получаю ошибку

```
неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: static class std::locale::id std::codecvt<char16_t,char,struct _Mbstatet>::id" (?id@?$codecvt@_SDU_Mbstatet@@@std@@2V0locale@2@A)"
```

Подскажите как пофиксить?

Код конвертора

```
#include "utfconvert.h"

string utf16_to_utf8(const u16string &s)
{
    wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> conv;
    return conv.to_bytes(s);
}

string utf32_to_utf8(const u32string &s)
{
    wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> conv;
    return conv.to_bytes(s);
}

std::u16string utf8_to_utf16(const string &s)
{
    //wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> conv;
    //return conv.from_bytes(s);
}

std::u16string utf32_to_utf16(const u32string &s)
{
    wstring_convert<codecvt_utf16<char32_t>, char32_t> conv;
    string bytes = conv.to_bytes(s);
    return u16string(reinterpret_cast<const char16_t*>(bytes.c_str()), bytes.length() / sizeof(char16_t));
}

std::u32string utf8_to_utf32(const string &s)
{
    wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> conv;
    return conv.from_bytes(s);
}

std::u32string utf16_to_utf32(const u16string &s)
{
    const char16_t *pData = s.c_str();
    wstring_convert<codecvt_utf16<char32_t>, char32_t> conv;
    return conv.from_bytes(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(pData), reinterpret_cast<const char*>(pData + s.length()));
}
```

Comment: Переписать все заново используя ICU

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то VS2017 поддерживает `codecvt`, просто выдает предупреждение насчет "deprecated". Так что ошибка скорее всего получается из-за настроек проекта.

Решение комитета по стандартизации удалить из языка совершенно необходимое средство довольно спорное - это мягко говоря, а хотелось бы сказать грубо. Но приходится как-то с этим жить, так что лучше сразу ориентироваться на другие варианты.

Один вариант - это [ICU Project](http://site.icu-project.org/home). Решение исчерпывающее, но настолько монструозное и неудобное, что его и советовать не хочется.

По личному опыту могу порекомендовать [UTF-CPP](https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp). Маленькая и быстрая библиотека шаблонов с достаточно адекватной [документацией](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/). Поддерживает UTF8/16/32.

Наверняка найдется что-то еще, но я остановился на UTF-CPP, пока устраивает полностью.